# Declaring and override function in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio to write javascript/jquery. Example, I type:

```
$('#selector').text('foo')
```

then I select `text` and press `F12`. VS would show me the file `jquery-2.2.3.intellisense.js`, and automatically scroll down to to fucntion:

```
  'text': function() {
    /// <signature>
    ///   <summary>Set the content of each element in the set of matched elements to the specified text.</summary>
    ///   <param name="textString" type="String">A string of text to set as the content of each matched element.</param>
    ///   <returns type="jQuery" />
    /// </signature>
    /// <signature>
    ///   <summary>Set the content of each element in the set of matched elements to the specified text.</summary>
    ///   <param name="function(index, text)" type="Function">A function returning the text content to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old text value as arguments.</param>
    ///   <returns type="jQuery" />
    /// </signature>
  }
```

I know that it only contains the description of the function. I want to do that, too.

Declaring a function with some descriptions in a place, and override (implement) it in another place. Like this:

```
// first
var Add = function (a, b) {
    /// <signature>
    ///   <sumary>Add 2 numbers</sumary>
    ///   <returns type="Number" />
    /// </signature>
};

// second
@override
@**
 * Add 2 numbers
 * @param {Number} a: Number a
 * @param {Number} b: Number b
 * @return {Number}
*/
var Add = function (a, b) {
    return a + b
};
```

Now, when I type:

```
var sum = Add(2, 3);
```

I select `Add` and press `F12`, I want VS would hit to `the first` function (not the second).

So, my question: how can I do that?

Comment: You can't just do this.

Comment: You should tag your question with `visual-studio`. Proper use of tags helps other people, among others to answer you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to open the file `jquery-2.2.3.intellisense.js` and the function to `intellisense.annotate(jQuery, {});`

```
intellisense.annotate(jQuery, {
    'Add': function () {
        /// <signature>
        ///   <summary>Add 2 numbers</summary>
        ///   <param name="a" type="Number">Number a</param>
        ///   <param name="b" type="Number">Number b</param>
        ///   <returns type="Number" />
        /// </signature>
    }
});
```

In the file `another.js`:

```
$.fn.extend({
    /**
      * Add 2 numbers
      * param {Number} a: Number a
      * param {Number} a: Number b
      * return {Number}
    */
    Add: function (a, b) {
        return a + b
    }
});
```

Test:

```
$('#selector').Add(2, 3)
```

Select `Add` and press `F12`, VS would point to the function intellisense correctly (although the implement of function `Add` mean nothing in this case :))